# A function that can make caller return

Tags: bash

I am writing some BASH script and I want it have some error handling mechanism:

```
function f()
{
  command1 || { echo "command1 failed"; return 1; }
  command2 || { echo "command2 failed"; return 1; }
  command3 || { echo "command3 failed"; return 1; }
  command4 || { echo "command4 failed"; return 1; }
}
```

I want to make this repetitive structure more readable by defining some function:

```
function print_and_return()
{
  echo "$@"
  # some way to exit the caller function
}
```

so that I can write function `f` as

```
function f()
{
  command1 || print_and_return "command1 failed"
  command2 || print_and_return "command2 failed"
  command3 || print_and_return "command3 failed"
  command4 || print_and_return "command4 failed"
}
```

What's the best way to achieve this?  Thanks.

Comment: What's wrong with what you have? It works as-is.

Comment: @CodeGnome, it is not very readable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can use `set -e`, though you have to be careful since it exits the shell:

```
function f()
{
    (
    set -e
    command1
    command2
    command3
    command4
    )
}
```

As long as the commands diagnose any problems, this function will stop when the first command fails.

Test version:

```
function f()
{
    (
    set -e
    true
    echo true
    true
    echo true
    false
    echo false
    true
    echo true
    )
}

echo calling function
f
echo still here
```

Output:

```
calling function
true
true
still here
```

NB: When I used the sequence:

```
echo calling function
if f
then echo still here - f passed
else echo still here - f failed
fi
```

Then the function behaved differently under bash 3.2.48 on Mac OS X 10.7.4:

```
calling function
true
true
false
true
still here - f passed
```

So, inventive, but not wholly reliable.

Comment: Worth noting is that `set -e` and the `ERR` trap are generally [not to be encouraged](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105). They're quirky and unreliable (except for the reliable monthly question they generate on the mailing lists).

Comment: @ormaaj: I'm a little surprised that my answer was accepted.  Your x-ref is interesting. The `set -e` mechanism works reliably in Bourne and Korn shells. If `bash` hasn't yet made up its mind how `set -e` is supposed to work, that is disappointing (the article cites differences between 4.0 and 4.1, etc).  As for `let` returning any status other than zero on success; that is a bug, IMNSHO.  It should return 0 when the expression is evaluated successfully, and non-zero on failure, triggering `set -e` action.

Comment: I think `let` works correctly. The FAQ just points out the post-increment being possibly confusing, and more importantly contrasting with `((expr))` being a "compound command" which made it an exception to the rule... in old Bashes. But yeah I'm sure it's possible to use `set -e` if you know exactly how it behaves. I've seen [clever usages](https://mailman.research.att.com/pipermail/ast-users/2012q1/003463.html). More often it's just indicative of taking a bad approach. This question is just a hard problem to solve generally - eventually it'll turn into "how to do function objects in Bash?"

Answer (score 2):

#### The Problem

You want to:

1. Pretty up your code a bit.
2. DRY up the code a little.
3. Stop execution the first time a command fails.

#### One Possible Solution

You can refactor your code. For example:

```
print_and_return() {
  echo "command failed: $@" >&2
  return 1
}

commands=("cmd1" "cmd2" "cmd3" "cmd4")

for cmd in "${commands[@]}"; do
    { $cmd || print_and_return "$cmd"; } || break
done
```

Comment: This is generally a better approach than `set -e`, but the code is flawed. [You can't store a command in a variable](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050). Arrays are a good way to store commands, but not collections of commands. You're also applying word-splitting and pathname expansion to the unquoted use of `$cmd`, which is extremely likely to not do what you expect. At best, if the quoting problem wasn't there, you could run commands with no args this way. Otherwise a different solution is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Similiar to [CodeGnome's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11060903/296974), but without using arrays (which might not be present in every shell):

```
function callthem()
{
    for cmd; do # short form for "for cmd in "$@"; do"
        "$cmd" || { echo "$cmd failed." >&2; return 1; }
    done
}

function f()
{
    callthem command1 command2 command3 command4
    # or maybe even
    callthem command{1,2,3,4}
}
```